# ajax in codeigniter showing only false message even when the value exist in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to check if value exist in database in my CodeIgniter website using AJAAX. I have written the following code:

```html
<input id="username" name="pincode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pincode">
<input id="prodid" name="prodid" value="<?php echo $prodid;?>" type="hidden">

<button type="button" onclick="check_if_exists();" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
```

```js
function check_if_exists() {

  var username = $("#username").val();
  var prodid = $("#prodid").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/homecontroller/filename_exists",
    data: {
      username: username,
      prodid: prodid
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == true) {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">' + msg + "</span>");
      } else {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">Delivery Not Available at ' + username + '</span>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
              function filename_exists()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('pincode');
    $prodid = $this->input->post('prodid');
    $exists = $this->product->filename_exists($prodid);
   
 
    if ($exists) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
```

```html
  function filename_exists($prodid)
                  {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('id', $prodid);
  $this->db->from('product');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result_array();
  return $result;
                  }
```

I am only getting the message that the value doesn't exist even if the value is there in database.

Comment: Have you checked that the input value is transferred to the server?

Comment: @dspillai how do i check that

Comment: your data in DB may be integer but the data in your request is string

Comment: I also want to say that you are trying to get the data from the database that actually not necesssary. If you only want to check whether the data exist, why do you want to collect it? Rewrite like this **$query = $this->db->select('id')->from('product')->where('id',$prodid)->get(); if($q->num_rows()) return true;**

Comment: Use echo, not returnif ($exists) {
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;

    }

Comment: @dspillai bro i changed it as you said but now am getting page not fund error in console, shopping/index.php/homecontroller/filename_exists:1 Faile

Comment: @HolaPz my data in db is integer, can you tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using AJAX not the form submission method, so in back-end post() method won't work
2. To transfer a value from server in php, one method is echo, but return is wrong here.
   Please rewrite your code like this
   **View**

```js
function check_if_exists() {

  var username = $("#username").val();
  var prodid = $("#prodid").val();
  var transfer = [username,prodid];
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/homecontroller/filename_exists",
    data: {result: JSON.stringify(transfer)},
    success: function(response) {
      if (response) {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">' + msg + "</span>");
      } else {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">Delivery Not Available at ' + username + '</span>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```js
function filename_exists()
{
    $post = json_decode($_POST['result']);
    $username = $post[0];
    $prodid = $post[1];
    $exists = $this->product->filename_exists($prodid);
    echo $exists;
}
```

**Modal**

```js
function filename_exists($prodid)
{
  $this->db->select('id');
  $this->db->where('id', $prodid);
  $this->db->from('product');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows()) return true;
}
```

```
enter code here
```